# Setting string in intent

Tags: android, android-intent

***case 1: App startup***

App launch -> SplashActivity (splash screen, **no string intent is set**) -> LoginAactivity.

***case 2: After resetting password***

PasswordResetActivity (**set string intent, email to pre-populate in LoginActivity**) ->LoginActivity.

**LoginActivity, onCreate**

> String email = getIntent().getExtras().get("email");
>
> if(email == null) {
>       //should execute in case1 }
>   else {
>       //should execute in case2 }

But this is throwing null pointer exception when the app is launched? What is the work around ?

Comment: Please post code to pass string from PasswordResetActivity.

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent(); if(intent != null)

Comment: this String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");

Comment: if(intent.hasExtra("email")) worked for me as suggested by Rishab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try implementing this way**

```
private void someMethod() {

    String email = null;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("email"))
        email = intent.getStringExtra("email");

    if (email == null) {
        //should execute in case1
    } else {
        //should execute in case2
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you execute the `LoginActivity` after the `SplashScreen`, the `LoginActivity` hasn't extras, so `getIntent().getExtras()` is `null` and `getIntent().getExtras().get("email")` throws a `NullPointerException`.

You can avoid it in many ways, but a solution can be:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
   String email = getIntent().getExtras().get("email");
   if (email != null)
    {
      //should execute in case2
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in the login  activity. First we will fetch the intent values in a bundle. After that check whether the bundle has intent values or not, then we will fetch the email value. By this way the null-pointer crash can be stopped. Even if the key is changed also, it won't get crashed, in the below case it will keep the email string value as null. In general, always check the null before you proceed.

```
//Fetching the intent extra values using the bundle...
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

// Checking whether there is value in bundle or not...
if (bundle != null) {
String email = bundle.getString("email");
}
```